# replace fragment with fragment i selected in tablayout

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

i'm trying to replace fragments in ViewPager and send data to each fragment using some classes here is my code:

```
    tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame);

    viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new NewFragment(),"New"); // `new NewFragment()` should be inside `FragmentPagerAdapter.getItem()`
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new AllFragments(),"All"); // `new AllFragments()` should be inside `FragmentPagerAdapter.getItem()`
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new PopularFragment(),"Most Rating"); // `new PopularFragment()` should be inside `FragmentPagerAdapter.getItem()`
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new FavouritesFragment(),"My Rate"); // `new FavouritesFragment()` should be inside `FragmentPagerAdapter.getItem()`

    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

here is the data that i need to put it on all fragments:

```
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("categori",getIntent().getStringExtra("category"));
```

this code is  gave me white fragment in all.

```
    Fragment New = new NewFragment();
    Fragment all = new AllFragments();
    New.setArguments(args);
    all.setArguments(args);
    if(New != null && New.isVisible()){
        chooseFragment(New);
    }else if(New != null && New.isVisible()){
        chooseFragment(all);
    }
}

public void chooseFragment(Fragment fr){
    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.frame, fr)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
}
```

please help me i search too much but i didn't found the answer and thank you.

Comment: Whats this `if(New != null && New.isVisible()){
        chooseFragment(New);
    }else if(New != null && New.isVisible()){
        chooseFragment(all);
    }`? Both conditions are same?

Comment: Couldn't understand your question but you don't need to manage replacing tab fragments yourself. Just use [FragmentPagerAdapter](https://guides.codepath.com/android/viewpager-with-fragmentpageradapter)